# Radius of convergence and sum of $\sum_{n\ge 0}{\frac{\cos(n)x^n}{n!}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I want to determine the radius of convergence of the power series 
$$\sum_{n\ge 0}{\dfrac{\cos(n)x^n}{n!}}$$
The ratio test gives that for $x\not = 0$ we have that 
$$\left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}(x)}{a_n(x)}\right|=\frac{\cos(n+1)}{(n+1)\cos(n)}|x|$$ 
and i can't find this limit as $n\to \infty$.

Now suppose we have a radius of convergence $R$, then since 
$$\cos(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}n^{2k}}$$
hence
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {\frac{(-1)^kn^{2k}x^n}{n!(2k)!}} }=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\left[\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(n)^{2k}x^n}{n!}}\right]}$$
The next step is to determine the sum for each $k$:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(n)^{2k}x^n}{n!}}$$
Thank you for your help!!

Comment: $|\cos(n)| \leq 1$, so just use comparison test with $e^{|x|}$

Comment: Consider $\limsup \sqrt[n]{\lvert a_n\rvert}$. Cauchy-Hadamard is usually easier to deal with than the ratio test.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Sir, we have $a_n=\frac{\cos n}{n!}$ but then,$\lim  \sup \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} =\lim \sup \sqrt[n]{|\frac{\cos n}{n!}|}$. I could not see the lim sup :O I see that this is same as $\lim \sup \sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n!}}$ as supremum of $|\cos x|=1$.. But there fter i am struck... could you please help in this case..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Since $\limsup \sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n!}} = 0$, we're done. If one had $a_n = b_n\cos n$ with $\limsup \sqrt[n]{\lvert b_n\rvert} > 0$, then it would become complicated.

Comment: @DanielFischer : Oh.. I dont know how did i missed that small link... Thank you thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can, for a fixed $x$, threat the series as a usual series of numbers. Since 
$$0\leqslant |\cos n|\frac{|x|^n}{n!}\leqslant \frac{|x|^n}{n!}$$
and the series $\sum_{n\geqslant 0}\frac{t^n}{n!}$ is convergent for any positive $t$, we conclude that the power series is convergent for all $x$.

In order to compute the sum, write for $x$ a real number
$$\sum_{n\geqslant 0}\frac{(\cos n)x^n}{n!}=\Re\left(\sum_{n\geqslant 0}\frac{e^{in}x^n}{n!}\right)=\exp\left(xe^i\right).$$

Comment: OK Davide thanks, what about the sum of the series? Is my reasoning correct and is there any simpler way to determine this sum?

Comment: See edit. In you attempt, you have to justify you can switch the sums. And I'm not sure the last sums is easy to compute (for some values of $k$, yes, writing $n^2=n(n-1)+n$).

Comment: So it reamains to determine the real part of $exp(xe^i)$ and hence for a given real $x$ the sum of the series is  $e^{cos(1)x}cos(sin(1)x)$